# jQuery works once in php foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

Using Codeigniter 3.0.3

In the view there's a foreach loop to get all posts from database and at the end of each loop there's a form with post id to post data to controller to insert it to comments_table in database

But form works only in first post or first loop but another loops does not work

Inside model i just need commenter id from session and post id from post-id attr and comment_text from input[type="text"] called with comment-text

here's javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#addcommentajax').submit(function() {
        var commenter_id = "<?php echo $this->session->userdata('id'); ?>";
        var comment_text = $("#comment-text").val();
        var post_id = $(this).attr('post-id');
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url('home/addcomment'); ?>",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {commenter_id, post_id, comment_text},
                success: function(commented) {
                    if(commented == true) {
                        window.location.reload(true);
                        alert('commented');
                    }
                }
            });
    });
});
</script>
```

And here's the php foreach loop to display posts with his own comment form

```
              <?php if($allposts): ?>
                    <?php foreach ($allposts as $post): ?>
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="col-md-12" style="padding: 0;">
                                    <img class="img-rounded pull-left" src="<? echo base_url($post->image) ?>" width=30px height=30px>
                                    <div style="margin-top: 5px;">
                                        <a href="<? echo base_url('home?p=Profile&u='.$post->post_author) ?>"><small style="margin-left: 5px;"><?=$post->post_author?></small></a>
                                        <span style="font-size: 75%;" class="text-muted pull-right"><span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span>
                                        <?php $post_date = $post->post_date; $now = time(); $units = 1; ?>
                                            <? echo timespan($post_date, $now, $units) ?>
                                                ago</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                <hr class="myown">
                                <div class="col-md-12 text-muted"><small><?=$post->post_text?></small></div>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                <hr class="myown">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <?php if($this->users_model->liked($post->pid)): ?>
                                        <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm disabled"><span class="fa fa-check"></span> Liked</a>
                                        <?php else: ?>
                                            <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm like-btn" post-id="<?=$post->pid?>"><span data-toggle-tooltip="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Like" class="fa fa-thumbs-up fa-lg"></span></a>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                                <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#<?=$post->pid?>Comment"><span data-toggle-tooltip="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Comment" class="fa fa-comment fa-lg"></span></a>
                                                <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span data-toggle-tooltip="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Share" class="fa fa-share fa-lg"></span></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="pull-right-custom text-muted"><small><?=$post->post_likes?> Like - <?=$post->post_comments?> Comment</small></div>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                <div id="<?=$post->pid?>Comment" class="collapse">
                                    <br>
                                    <form name="addcommentajax" id="addcommentajax" post-id="<?=$post->pid?>" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <input type="text" id="comment-text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Add Comment">
                                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">Publish</button>
                        </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As written you have a repeating id, which is not allowed. No two elements should have the same id.

But classes may repeat, therefore change `addcommentajax` from an id to a class :

```
<form name="addcommentajax" post-id="<?=$post->pid?>" class="addcommentajax form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST">
```

And in jQuery, use the class selector instead of the id selector.

```
$('.addcommentajax').submit(function() {...});
```

Comment: your code works but in first loop it's catch `$("#comment-text").val();` but in another loops didn't catch the input value

Answer (score 0):

The `name` and `id` attribute of the form are `meant be unique`. In your loop you are assigning all the forms the same id and name. Hence your script takes the first occurence. Change your form name to a unique name and instead of using id as selector assign a class to the form.

eg: Assuming post ids are unique

```
<?php if($allposts): ?>
    <?php foreach ($allposts as $post): ?>
      ...................
      ...................
      <form name="addcommentajax<?=$post->pid?>" class="addcommentajax" data-post-id="<?=$post->pid?>" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST">
..................
................
</form>
<?php endforeach; ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
```

In javascript

```
$('.addcommentajax').submit(function() {
..........
.............
});
```

Comment: same problem it's post but didn't catch second input value it's catch only first input value i mean if i try to add comment from second loop it's post commenter_id from session and post_id but didn't post input value it's post NULL

Answer (score 0):

Solved by change class name of input every loop

I Used `class="comment-<?php echo $post->pid; ?>"` in input

And change in java script

From :

```
var comment_text = $("#comment-text").val();
var post_id = $(this).attr('post-id');
```

To:

```
var post_id = $(this).attr('post-id');
var comment_text = $(".comment-"+post_id).val();
```